# What is the right method to add text areas to Django?

Tags: django-forms, django-templates, django-widget

I have written python code that analyses two text sources and compares them.

I'd like to implement this dynamically via two text boxes that a user could either type into or manually upload. I have already begun coding this using HTML. Would it be better to implement a widget or the models instead to make the text area boxes?

Edit:

I wrote this question when I was just figuring Django out, so forgive me if it sounds confusing. But everyone starts somewhere. I'm unable to delete the question as contributions have been made already. YouTube courses proved helpful in learning the basics, if any beginners stumble upon this.

Comment: This is a bit vague, unfortunately.

Comment: What do you mean by 'implement models'? You don't implement models on html. You implement fields that you then use to create a model instance from in the backend. Models are abstractions, text boxes are concrete fields of data/input.

Comment: I mean that you can use models to initialise a text area, according the the website's documentation. @IanKirkpatrick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use a form object. Django has form objects (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms) that take a model and translate it into html elements. So I guess in a way, you implement the model but I want to stress that that's not actually what's happening from a technical standpoint. A better way to say it is that you're implementing forms. The reason I stress this so much is so that you understand what's really going on so that you don't have misunderstandings that end up costing you in code clarity and readability.

So to answer your question, you can implement django forms to do this very easily. The way you implement it depends on your models and how they are designed since the forms use the models to create the right html form elements. If you're dealing with one model that will be instantiated by the form input, create a model form. This will take the input from the form and create your model instance. If you're dealing with one form that uses multiple models, then use a generic form. In this case, you will have to write your own save method that does the actual logic of the form.

One other thing to add... No matter what, your end result will always be a widget on the HTML in the end. Django forms translate a model class into a form element with input elements. If you didn't use Django forms, you would still do the translating, but you would have to do it from scratch.

I hope this helps and that I correctly understood your question.